# react native notification issue, using background and navigation issue perhaps

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

curently i am using this 
React Native Push Notifications

and followed the example of creating an schedule notification to local notification when my app is minimized in android.

my problem is, i implement these codes

```
constructor(){
    super();

    this.handleAppStateChange = this.handleAppStateChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      seconds: 10
  };
}

componentDidMount(){
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
    this.getTitles();
}

componentWillUnmount(){
  AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
}

handleAppStateChange(appState){
  if(appState === 'background'){
       PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
      message: "SUMMER SALE IS ON!", 
      date: new Date(Date.now() + (this.state.seconds * 1000)) // in 60 secs
    });
  }
}
```

i implemented these codes in my home.js where home.js is basically my home page with a search bar. Problem is, when i search something and submit from home.js to searchResult.js (passing data with react navigation), the notification will trigger as well on the searchResult.js page.

it was suppose to be trigger when my app is minimize. How can i prevent the notification from triggering in searchResult.js?

EDIT:
this is my current App.js and i am not sure how should i implement the notification in here

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated', 'Module RCTImageLoader']);


import store from './store'; //Import the store

import Home from './components/home' //Import the component file
import Cart from './components/cart';
import SearchResults from './components/searchResults';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Root />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

const homeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { 
    screen: Home, 
    navigationOptions:{
         title: "test",
       headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#4050B5',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
    }
  },
   SearchResults: { 
    screen: SearchResults, 
    navigationOptions:{
         title: "Search Results",
       headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#4050B5',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold'
      }
    }
  }
})

const cartStack = createStackNavigator({
 Cart: {  
    screen: Cart, 
    navigationOptions:{
       title: "Shopping Cart",
     headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#4050B5',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
    }
  },
})

const Root = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: homeStack,   
  Cart: cartStack
},    
{ 
  initialRouteName : "Home", 
},
{
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = `user${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        } else if (routeName === 'Cart') {
          iconName = `cart${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        }

        // You can return any component that you like here! We usually use an
        // icon component from react-native-vector-icons
        //return <EvilIcons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'tomato',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    }
}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's good practice to handle app state changes at the highest level possible (App.js). Secondly, handleAppStateChange gets the *next* app state as its param, so for better control I think you should store the current appState in your component state, and then check to be sure that the state changed to something different than its current state. So your listener could look like `handleAppStateChange(nextAppState)` and the conditional in it could be `if (this.state.appState === 'inactive' && nextAppState === 'background')`
then don't forget to `setState({appState: nextAppState})` at the end of your listener. 
i think that should solve your issue but if not let me know.

Comment: i have edited my question above and include App.js code. Currently i am not sure how can i implement the notification there since i have redux and navigation together.

Comment: Just import { AppState } from react-native the same way you did in home.js and your listeners look fine, just use componentDidMount & componentWillUnmount to add your listener and remove it. move handleAppStateChange from home.js to App.js -- then implement the comparison of appState with nextAppState for better control within your handleAppState function. AppState doesn't depend on navigation or redux -- it's simply a react-native tool to determine if your app is active, backgrounded or inactive, and run some code when the AppState changes.